# How to extract a particular element from an object based on key in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a requirement where I need to extract an element/attribute from an JSON object based on a particular key. I am super confused here how to fetch.

```
{   "metadata":{
      "lastSyncTime":"2000-11-21T16:07:53",
      "dataFromDB":true
   },
   "allocationReports":[      {
         "allocatedUserCount":100,
         "healthGoalName":"Eat Healthier",
         "segments": [
            {segmentValue: "40-49", allocatedUserCount: 2}, 
            {segmentValue: "30-39", allocatedUserCount: 13},
            {segmentValue: "20-29", allocatedUserCount: 23}
         ]
      },
      {
         "allocatedUserCount":130,
         "healthGoalName":"Feel Happier",
         "segments": [
            {segmentValue: "40-49", allocatedUserCount: 20}, 
            {segmentValue: "30-39", allocatedUserCount: 3},
            {segmentValue: "20-29", allocatedUserCount: 53}
         ]
      },
  
      {
         "allocatedUserCount":150,
         "healthGoalName":"Quit Smoking",
         "segments": [
            {segmentValue: "40-49", allocatedUserCount: 19}, 
            {segmentValue: "30-39", allocatedUserCount: 1},
            {segmentValue: "20-29", allocatedUserCount: 22},
            {segmentValue: "10-19", allocatedUserCount: 47}
         ]
      }
   ],
   "overall":{
      "usersWithGoalCount":0,
      "registeredCount":500,
      "eligibleCount":280
   }
}
```

How can we extract the segments array based on healthgoalName. For example I have written a method which takes 'healthGoalName'(Let's say Quit Smoking) as argument.
This method should return -

```
"segments": [
   {segmentValue: "40-49", allocatedUserCount: 19}, 
   {segmentValue: "30-39", allocatedUserCount: 1},
   {segmentValue: "20-29", allocatedUserCount: 22},
   {segmentValue: "10-19", allocatedUserCount: 47}
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing can "return" `"key": [ ... ]`, because it's a key-value pair, not a value. Do you want the array?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes.. the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume the JSON in the question is showing the content of an object called `obj` which is available in the context of the method called `getSegments`. If that is not the case, you'll need to provide that object to the method as a second argument.

```js
function getSegments(healthGoalName)
{
    const allocationReport = obj.allocationReports.find(allocationReport => allocationReport.healthGoalName === healthGoalName);
    return allocationReport ? allocationReport.segments : null;
}
```

```js
function getSegments(healthGoalName)
{
    const allocationReport = obj.allocationReports.find(allocationReport => allocationReport.healthGoalName === healthGoalName);
    return allocationReport ? allocationReport.segments : null;
}

const obj =
{
    "metadata":{
      "lastSyncTime":"2000-11-21T16:07:53",
      "dataFromDB":true
   },
   "allocationReports":[      {
         "allocatedUserCount":100,
         "healthGoalName":"Eat Healthier",
         "segments": [
            {segmentValue: "40-49", allocatedUserCount: 2}, 
            {segmentValue: "30-39", allocatedUserCount: 13},
            {segmentValue: "20-29", allocatedUserCount: 23}
         ]
      },
      {
         "allocatedUserCount":130,
         "healthGoalName":"Feel Happier",
         "segments": [
            {segmentValue: "40-49", allocatedUserCount: 20}, 
            {segmentValue: "30-39", allocatedUserCount: 3},
            {segmentValue: "20-29", allocatedUserCount: 53}
         ]
      },
  
      {
         "allocatedUserCount":150,
         "healthGoalName":"Quit Smoking",
         "segments": [
            {segmentValue: "40-49", allocatedUserCount: 19}, 
            {segmentValue: "30-39", allocatedUserCount: 1},
            {segmentValue: "20-29", allocatedUserCount: 22},
            {segmentValue: "10-19", allocatedUserCount: 47}
         ]
      }
   ],
   "overall":{
      "usersWithGoalCount":0,
      "registeredCount":500,
      "eligibleCount":280
   }
};

const segments = getSegments("Quit Smoking");
console.log({ segments });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to first type the structure of your data, something like:

```js
interface Segment {
  segmentValue: string;
  allocatedUserCount: number;
}

interface AllocationReport {
  allocatedUserCount: number;
  healthGoalName: string;
  segments: Segment[];
}

interface Data {
  metadata: {
    lastSyncTime: string;
    dataFromDB: boolean;
  }
  allocationReports: AllocationReport[];
}
```

Then, you could code a function to get the `segments` as follows:

```js
const search = (data: Data, healthGoalName: string): Segment[] | undefined => {
  for (const allocationReport of data.allocationReports) {
    if (allocationReport.healthGoalName === healthGoalName) {
      return allocationReport.segments;
    }
  }

  return undefined;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

See notes in snippets

```js
const dataObject = {"metadata":{
    "lastSyncTime":"2000-11-21T16:07:53",
    "dataFromDB":true
 },
 "allocationReports":[      {
       "allocatedUserCount":100,
       "healthGoalName":"Eat Healthier",
       "segments": [
          {segmentValue: "40-49", allocatedUserCount: 2}, 
          {segmentValue: "30-39", allocatedUserCount: 13},
          {segmentValue: "20-29", allocatedUserCount: 23}
       ]
    },
    {
       "allocatedUserCount":130,
       "healthGoalName":"Feel Happier",
       "segments": [
          {segmentValue: "40-49", allocatedUserCount: 20}, 
          {segmentValue: "30-39", allocatedUserCount: 3},
          {segmentValue: "20-29", allocatedUserCount: 53}
       ]
    },

    {
       "allocatedUserCount":150,
       "healthGoalName":"Quit Smoking",
       "segments": [
          {segmentValue: "40-49", allocatedUserCount: 19}, 
          {segmentValue: "30-39", allocatedUserCount: 1},
          {segmentValue: "20-29", allocatedUserCount: 22},
          {segmentValue: "10-19", allocatedUserCount: 47}
       ]
    }
 ],
 "overall":{
    "usersWithGoalCount":0,
    "registeredCount":500,
    "eligibleCount":280
 }
}

function findSegments(data,query) {
    //if data layer is an object
    if(!Array.isArray(data)){
        return Object.entries(data).reduce((output,[key,val]) => {
          //and if property is an array
          if(Array.isArray(val)){
              //run recursion 
              output = findSegments(val, query);
              return output; 
          }
          //otherwise ignore
          return output;
        },{})
    //if data layer is an array
    } else {
        return data.reduce((output,ele)=> {
            //and if healthGoalName matches query ignore
            if(ele.healthGoalName === query) {
                //extract segments
               output.segments = ele.segments;
               return output;       
            }
            //otherwise ignore
            return output;              
        }, {})
    } 
}
//pass original data object and healthGoalName query value
console.log(findSegments(dataObject,"Quit Smoking"))
```